# Program with race conditions in Windows, but not in Ubuntu

Tags: java, multithreading, ubuntu, race-condition

In an assignment designed to highlight race conditions, we were given the following code

```
public class IncreaseDecrease {

    public static int IntegerVariable = 0;
    public static final int NUM_ITER = 5000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Increase inc;
        Decrease dec;

        while (true) {          
            inc = new Increase();
            dec = new Decrease();

            inc.start();
            dec.start();

            inc.join();
            dec.join();

            System.out.println(IntegerVariable);
            IntegerVariable = 0;
            Thread.sleep(750);
        }
    }   
}

class Increase extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < IncreaseDecrease.NUM_ITER; i++) {
            IncreaseDecrease.IntegerVariable++;
        }
    }
}

class Decrease extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < IncreaseDecrease.NUM_ITER; i++) {
            IncreaseDecrease.IntegerVariable--;
        }
    }
}
```

this code which would be expected to print 0 if each thread can update the value before the other one reads it, but that does not happen due to race conditions, it can print any value between -5000000 and 5000000.
I ran that code on windows and repl.it, and it gave the expected output:

`-310951
-1918567
-3374495
-3219135
-2286639
-3221055
-3794319
-2442047
-2776415
-3617391`

But on Ubuntu, when I ran it, it gave 0 every time.

My question is, why does this happen? Does Ubuntu manage threads differently, or is it just a special case for my computer?

Edit:
After putting the increment in a different method and adding one more operation to it, I observed the race condition. Here's the final code:

```
public class IncreaseDecrease {

    public static int IntegerVariable = 0;
    public static final int NUM_ITER = 5000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Increase inc;
        Decrease dec;

        while (true) {          
            inc = new Increase();
            dec = new Decrease();

            inc.start();
            dec.start();

            inc.join();
            dec.join();

            System.out.println(IntegerVariable);
            IntegerVariable = 0;
            Thread.sleep(750);
        }
    }
    public static void increment ()
    {
        IntegerVariable++;
        double a = Math.pow(3, 7);
    }
    public static void decrement()
    {
        IntegerVariable--;
        double a = Math.pow(3, 7);
    }
}

class Increase extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < IncreaseDecrease.NUM_ITER; i++) {
            IncreaseDecrease.increment();
        }
    }
}

class Decrease extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < IncreaseDecrease.NUM_ITER; i++) {
            IncreaseDecrease.decrement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you booting into Ubuntu or just run it in VM like VirtualBox? Maybe in VM only single CPU core is assigned?

Comment: yes. I am using Ubuntu on VirtualBox with only one core.

Comment: Using it with 4 cores showed some race condition just for the first 2 iterations, but using Vice Simunov's answer even with 1 core showed the results I wanted to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd go out on a limb and claim that Hotspot under Linux using the server compiler while it doesn't on Windows is the more likely explanation: The compiler can replace the whole loop with a single expression which is something that HotSpot is definitely capable of. Adding any native method will make that impossible thereby making it much more likely to observe the race condition

I would guess that this might be the case as well.

Have you tried making your **IntegerVariable volatile**? This would prevent some compiler optimization that might occur.

```
public static volatile int IntegerVariable = 0;
```

Comment: By adding a native method which did more work than just increment the variable, I was able to observe the effects of the race condition. Thanks! I would also love to get the link to the article you are quoting.

Comment: It's a comment on the answer below :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a common misconception about threads in Java that they truly and efficiently interleave processing evenly. That is actually not quite true and different JVMs on different systems work differently.

It all arises from when the JVM decides to switch threads. A JVM will probably switch threads whenever it hits a `Thread.sleep()` or a blocking method such as as `synchronized` or a `lock` but generally if a thread is not doing anything that involves blocking etc it will let the thread run.

Your loops ar spinning on incrementing and decrementing a value with no pause. If you add a `Thread.sleep(0)` call in your loops you will probably see a difference because you are offering the JVM many more opportunities to switch your thread out/in.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < IncreaseDecrease.NUM_ITER; i++) {
        IncreaseDecrease.IntegerVariable--;
        // Add this.
        Thread.sleep(0);
    }
```

Comment: You can also use `Thread.yield()` instead of `Thread.sleep(0)`

Comment: This is rather misleading. No modern JVM uses green threads, they all use native threads which means they don't schedule anything. Consequently whether Thread.Sleep causes a context switch or not is an implementation detail of the underlying syscall.

Comment: I'd go out on a limb and claim that Hotspot under Linux using the server compiler while it doesn't on Windows is the more likely explanation: The compiler can replace the whole loop with a single expression which is something that HotSpot is definitely capable of. Adding any native method will make that impossible thereby making it much more likely to observe the race condition.